# How to set video to play on all major browsers on Windows, Mac, Android, and iOS devices

Tags: flash, video, cross-browser, html5-video

We have a requirement to create a video demo of certain products. What is the best way to make sure that the video plays on as many browsers as possible on all popular platforms?

Current implementation: we just have Flash videos that load in a Flash player.

Answer (score 1):

If a hosted service is a viable option for you, paid accounts at sites like Vimeo and Wistia will serve Flash video to desktop browsers and HTML5 video for smartphones and other mobile devices like the iPad and upcoming tablets from Samsung, Blackberry, etc.

If you'll be doing all of the hosting yourself, I recommend using the HTML5 video tag with a simple fallback to Flash. The excellent [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) script handles most of the hard stuff for you and even allows you to [build custom embed codes](http://videojs.com/embed-builder/).

Basically, the HTML would look like this:

```
<video width="640" height="360" poster="poster.png" controls preload>
    <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' /> <!-- This video file is for Safari, Chrome and smartphones running iOS and Android, it will also be referenced later in the Flash fallback for Internet Explorer -->
    <source src="video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' /> <!-- This video file is for Firefox, Opera, and is also supported by Chrome -->

    <object id="flash_fallback" width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"> <!-- This calls on FlowPlayer, an excellent third party Flash video player -->
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["poster.png", {"url": "video.mp4","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' /> <!-- Notice here you're calling the same .mp4 file as above -->
        <img src="poster.png" width="640" height="360" alt="Poster Image" title="No video playback capabilities." /> <!-- If the browser can't handle any of the HTML5 video files and doesn't have Flash installed, they'll just get the poster frame as shown here -->
    </object>
</video>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Lets say if i use the videjs option. Then how do i convert flash video to MP4, Webm, Ogg?

Comment: Dive Into HTML5 does an excellent job of explaining the best ways to encode for each format, check it out here: http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html#firefogg --- Alternatively, if you have the budget, services like Zencoder offer great encoding options and charge only based on the duration of your videos: http://zencoder.com/

Answer (score 0):

<del>Flash would not be playable on any iOS devices.</del>

Edit:  I misread the question.  If you use youtube to host the video and embed a youtube video, you can then play the video on an iOS device through the youtube app.  That would be one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use embeddable video players that have fallback to HTML5 versions on your website page (eg, [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/)). That way you'll get predictable/stable playback using Flash on all browsers, and HTML5 playback on devices that support it (Android, iOS, others).